# HTML code below works in IE 8, but not in FF 11. Can anyone tell me how to get this to work in both IE and FF?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML code below works fine in IE 8, but not in FF 11. Although the code seems to take different browsers into account, for some reason FF does not do the trick. Can someone please tell me how to get this to work in both IE and FF? The idea is to rotate several clickable pictures.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ilayer id='l1'>
<layer id='l2'>
    <div id='l1'>
        <div id='l3' style='position:relative'>
        </div>
    </div>
</layer>
</ilayer>
<script language='JavaScript'>
<!--

var bannerArray = new Array();
var myCount=0;
// Banner Code Assignment
bannerArray[0] = "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image1.jpg' BORDER=0 height='50'/></a>";
bannerArray[1] = "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image2.jpg' BORDER=0 height='50'/></a>";
bannerArray[2] = "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image3.jpg'     BORDER=0 height='50'/></a>";

bannerRotate();

function bannerRotate() {

if(myCount > bannerArray.length-1){myCount=0;}

// Write out rotation

if (document.all){          // it is IE
    document.all.l3.innerHTML=bannerArray[myCount];
}

else if (document.layers){  // it is NN

document.layers.l1.document.layers.l2.document.open();
document.layers.l1.document.layers.l2.document.write(bannerArray[myCount]);
document.layers.l1.document.layers.l2.document.close();
}
setTimeout('bannerRotate()', 1000);
myCount++;
}
// -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the title, you should give at least a hint of what you are trying to do. You should also describe better what you are trying to do and exactly how it “doesn’t work”.

Comment: This HTML and JavaScript seems to be ancient, I doubt it would work in any modern browser. You'd better rewrite the whole code.

Comment: doctype, doctype, doctype.

Comment: `// it is NN`!! So who is using Nestcape Navigator these days?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a DOCTYPE.

This is an important part of a HTML document. Without it, IE see the HTML as invalid and render it in Quirks Mode. Other browsers won't.

When I is in Quirks mode, it is basically rendering the page as it would have done in IE5.

This is why you are seeing the page look different in IE vs FF. Firefox is actually rendering it correctly; it is IE that is wrong.

Add a valid DOCTYPE to make IE render it correctly. If you don't know which doctype to use, use this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This will make the page render the same in all browsers.

It will, however, be IE that changes, so if you think it's rendering fine in IE now, then you'll probably have to make some changes to your layout to fix it.

Hope that helps.

In addition, your Javascript code is very badly obsolete. You will need to consider rewriting all of that from scratch. Nobody uses `document.all` or `document.layers` any more. However, the doctype is the main thing that is making your page render incorrectly in the first instance.

Comment: I think `DOCTYPE` wasn't even born when this snippet was originally written. Also `layer` or `ilayer` tags can't be found in any documentation anymore, they just that old...

Comment: I'm absolutely stunned by the number of answers I got in such a short time! Compliments to you all and thanks for hinting me in the right direction. I found the codesnippet somewhere on the internet and thought of using it in my project. As a total newby (but willing to learn), I tried posting my problem here as I noticed it did not work in FF. And voila! Barely 10 minutes later I have things working! Magic. Thanks to you all.

Comment: @Marten u should give these guys some votes up and accept answer if you solved your problem thx to them :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.all` and `document.layers` are proprietary and obsolete. Use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it work then?
the if (document.all) statement only returns true when used in IE, otherwise it should branch to the else if.

Comment: @Marten, right but document.layers won't be matched by any modern browser either.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `if (document.all)` with `if (document)` and it will work in Firefox.

It will, but no *really*, **don't do that**! That's based on some almighty hacks.

Where-ever you got that code from, stop using it NOW.

There's plenty of tutorials out on the web that will show you how to rotate the display of images in a modern fashion. Go and find one.

Answer (score 0):

Lets bring this code into the 21st century, and don't forget the docype!!!!

HTML

```
<ul id="banner">
    <li id="bannerItem1"><a href="http://www.google.com.au"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x150/FF0000/FFFFFF/&text=Image1" /></a></li>
    <li id="bannerItem2"><a href="http:/jquery.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x150/00FF00/FFFFFF&text=Image2" /></a></li>
    <li id="bannerItem3"><a href="http://www.google.com.au"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x150/0000FF/FFFFFF&text=Image3" /></a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
#banner 
{
    list-style:none; /*Turn Off List Styling */
}

#banner li
{
display:none; /*Hide the List Items*/
}

#banner li#bannerItem1
{
    display:block;/*Show The First One */
}
```

Javascript

```
var listItems = document.getElementById("banner").getElementsByTagName("li");
var limiter = 0;//this is to stop it infinatly looping...optional
var activeNode = 0;

var t = setInterval(function(){bannerRotate()},1000);
function bannerRotate() {

    var listItemsCount = listItems.length;
    //LOOP THROUGH  List Items
    for(i = 0; i < listItemsCount; i++)
    {
        //Turn off all but next active node
        if(i != activeNode +1)
       {
              listItems[i].style.display = "none";
       }
        //Check if next active node is outside the list range
      else if((activeNode + 1) < listItemsCount)
      {
           listItems[activeNode +1].style.display = "block"
      }
    }

    activeNode++;
    if(activeNode >= listItemsCount)
    {
        listItems[0].style.display = "block";
        activeNode = 0;
    }

    if(limiter++ > 4)
    {    
       clearInterval(t);
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hj78T/